# How to create a file with filename as key of dictionary

Tags: python

I have a some default contents

```
import json
import defaultdict
```

I have a dictionary `{'1':'print (This is test file)', '2': 'print (This is test file)'}`

I need to create 2 text file `1.txt, 2.txt` which is key of dictionary

The dictionary will be having any number of k,v for showing example I have put two

The expected out is

```
1.txt
import json
import defaultdict
print (This is test file)

2.txt
import json
import defaultdict
print (This is test file)
```

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: @azro i have looped key value pairs but not open able to created the file

Comment: Share the code of you tries please

Comment: @azroo for k,v in dict.items(); with open('k','w+') as fr:

Comment: Edit your post and add it, not in comment

Comment: @azro after this how to write that already some default content is there. steps `: 1. create a files with k by looping  .items()2. Add the extension `.txt` to each filename  3.with open(k,w+)  add the default content and write

Comment: @azro thanks for answer. as you told my loop thought was not correct

Comment: @azro why you vote more negative?

Comment: That's isn't me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may open `k` and not `'k'`

```
imports = ["import json", "import defaultdict"]
d = {'1': 'print ("This is test file")', '2': 'print ("This is test file")'}
for k, v in d.items():
    with open(k + ".py", 'w') as fr:
        for imp in imports:
            fr.write(imp + "\n")
        fr.write(v)
```